# python regex to group numbers

Tags: python, regex

im trying to caputre numbers from that kind of a string:

```
"30098.904999  5  ABC                    Da   d 8 06 01 20 00 80 11 C0 04"
```

first i remove all whitespaces:

```
test = ' '.join(test.split())
```

then im trying to apply pattern:

```
pattern  = r"(\d+.\d+) (\d+) ABC Da d 8 (\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d) (\d\d)"
```

however, still got none result:

```
    result = re.search(pattern, s)
    print ("result: " + str(result.groups(0)))

  print ("result: " + str(result.groups(0)))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

if i change frist number to 50.309951, then it works. 
First number is a timestamp and  amount of numbers in it can vary..

Any help highly welcomed! :)
thx in advance
j.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just split the string after removing spaces chars?

```
test = ' '.join(test.split())
```

like this?

You will receive an array of items

```
['30098.904999', '5', 'ABC', 'Da', 'd', '8', '06', '01', '20', '00', '80', '11', 'C0', '04']
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because of `C0` which not matched with `\d\d`. You can use `\d\w` for that part. But as a more general approach you can use `re.findall()` to capture all numbers:

```
In [24]: test = "30098.904999  5  ABC                    Da   d 8 06 01 20 00 80 11 C0 04"

In [27]: re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', test)
Out[27]: ['30098.904999', '5', '8', '06', '01', '20', '00', '80', '11', '0', '04']
# If you want C0 too:
In [28]: re.findall(r'\w?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', test)
Out[28]: ['30098.904999', '5', '8', '06', '01', '20', '00', '80', '11', 'C0', '04']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to use `split` as you can use `\s+` to match 1 or more whitespace
2. Your regex also needs correction.

You can use this:

```
(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+ABC\s+Da\s+d\s+8\s+(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})\s+(\d{2})\s+([A-Z]\d)\s+(\d{2})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sz3GId/3)